# Running Maven for Gephi

Tags: maven, netbeans, gephi

I would like to create a plugin for Gephi but I got an error when running Maven and the project is not supported since 4 years... I already posted [my question as an issue](https://github.com/gephi/gephi-plugins/issues/226) but I think no one will answer me now.

I forked the git and tried to follow instructions in the [`README`](https://github.com/gephi/gephi-plugins/blob/master/README.md) to create my own plugin, but when I run this command :

```
mvn clean package
```

I constantly get this error :

> **[ERROR]** Failed to execute goal on project `gephi-plugins`: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.gephi:gephi-plugins:pom:0.9.2: Failed to collect dependencies at org.gephi:gephi:tar.gz:linux:0.9.2 -> org.netbeans.cluster:platform:pom:RELEASE82: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.netbeans.cluster:platform:pom:RELEASE82: Could not transfer artifact org.netbeans.cluster:platform:pom:RELEASE82 from/to maven-default-http-blocker (http://0.0.0.0/): Blocked mirror for repositories: [netbeans (http://bits.netbeans.org/nexus/content/groups/netbeans/, default, releases)] -> **[Help 1]**

I'm new with Maven and issues [#77](https://github.com/gephi/gephi-plugins/issues/77) and [#214](https://github.com/gephi/gephi-plugins/issues/214) didn't help me, I just followed instructions in the [`README`](https://github.com/gephi/gephi-plugins/blob/master/README.md) file.

I followed the link given by the error and a blank page with this text appeared :

> Repository decommissioned. Please refer to https://netbeans.apache.org/about/oracle-transition.html for more information.

And after clicking the link above, I thought this part was interesting :

> As of March the 6th, 2021, we’ll be standing on our own feet, and all the Apache NetBeans Project source and convenience binaries will be hosted by the [Apache Infra Team](https://www.apache.org/dev/infrastructure.html).

And then, a "new" code for handling netbeans repository

```xml
<build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>netbeans</id>
            <name>NetBeans</name>
            <url>http://netbeans.apidesign.org/maven2/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
<build>
```

Is that possible that the `pom.xml` file is not up to date ? Or am I missing something ?

I spoke with someone who already used Maven at the office and he said that none of [`gephi` repositories](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.gephi) are working with Maven, all of them display the error.

Thanks for the help !

Comment: After forwarding this at the FB Group for Gephi, I got [this](https://www.facebook.com/groups/gephi/posts/10160038176907565/?comment_id=10160040387092565&notif_id=1624286834509240&notif_t=group_comment&ref=notif) comment. I know it doesn't really help, but doesn't seem to be more on that.

Comment: @YannisP. thanks for your answer, but I'm not able to see the post since the group is private. I found a solution to my problem and it solve everything. In fact, it was quite simple... I will update my issue in the gephi-plugin git too and hope one developer will modify the outdated files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally the solution was quite simple :

The NetBeans repositories have indeed changed, so, in `modules/pom.xml` :

```xml
<repository>
    <id>netbeans</id>
    <name>NetBeans</name>
    <url>http://bits.netbeans.org/nexus/content/groups/netbeans/</url>
    <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
    </snapshots>
</repository>
```

We have to change the `<url>` tag to :

```xml
<url>http://netbeans.apidesign.org/maven2/</url>
```

I did that and it didn't work because my Maven version **didn't support non secure url repositories (http)** and I need to add a "s" in order to make it works.

```xml
<url>https://netbeans.apidesign.org/maven2/</url>
```

For a reason that I don't know, the project still not compile and we have to go to the parent `pom.xml` on the root folder and add the same NetBeans repository than above.

After doing that it compile.

I don't know if this is normal, but I'm new to Maven and I didn't know : if you want to use some gephi packages in your module (and wou want) you have to add them into `module/YourModule/pom.xml` in the `<dependencies>` tag ! Like that :

```xml
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.gephi</groupId>
        <artifactId>layout-api</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.gephi</groupId>
        <artifactId>graph-api</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- ... -->
</dependencies>
```

I tested it with the [GridLayout plugin](https://github.com/gephi/gephi-plugins-bootcamp/tree/master/modules/LayoutPluginExample/src/main/java/org/gephi/plugins/example/layout) from the [Gephi Plugins Bootcamp](https://github.com/gephi/gephi-plugins-bootcamp) and it worked.